# Why can't capture rewritten packet

Tags: linux, openwrt, tcpreplay

I'm using tcpdump and tcpreplay in ubuntu for capturing packet and resending(with rewriting and openwrt for ap mode in raspberry pi.

My problem is that I cannot capture resent packet.

This is my network  :

```
     A          ---->        B(RPI)           ----------->     C
192.168.0.199      eth0.          wlan0      |             192.168.2.172
               192.168.0.100    192.168.2.1  | 
                                              ------------>     D
                                                           192.168.2.222
```

I sent packet(using nping) from A to B, and used portforwarding

nping in A :

```
nping --udp --dest-port 7777 --dest-ip 192.168.0.100
```

portforwarding in B using iptables :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.222
```

So, I done here.

And I write this in D

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 dst port 7777 -w packet.pcap
tcprewrite -i packet.pcap -o packet_rewrite.pcap -D 192.168.2.222:192.168.2.172
tcpreplay -i wlan0 --topspeed packet_rewrite.pcap
```

But, in C, I cannot capture modified packet...

```
tcpdump dst port 7777
```

I really want to know why i can't...please let me know
and i'm really sorry my explain is not good....

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot an explanation. I did success tcpdump, tcprewrite in D.

Answer (score 0):

further search.. I captured packets in B (wlan0)
Because i edited packet's source mac to my ubuntu wlan mac address...
But as before, I cannot capture packets in C...
[This is captured packets in B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDZG3.png)

and even replayed packet didn't pass iptables...

**I solved!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

I had to change dmac to C's mac address....I was stupid....